# How to use java module in Scala

Tags: scala, module, playframework

How to use a module written in java to be used in scala playframework project(for ex pdf module in playframework only available for java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a clear distinction between java/scala modules in play 2.x, although you may experience some problems running  modules labeled as "scala" in java project and vice versa.

I have used pdf module just OK in scala project, my dependency is `"pdf" % "pdf_2.10" % "0.5",`
Following `Action` renders pdf from sample template named `testPdf`:

```
def renderSamplePdf() =   Action {      
    SimpleResult(
        header = ResponseHeader(OK, Map(
            CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> (s"""attachment; filename="document.pdf"; filename*=UTF-8''""" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("document.pdf", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20")),
            CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/pdf")),
            body =  Enumerator(PDF.toBytes(views.html.testPdf())))
}
```

Note that this module version has some bugs, like it produces errors when you use absolute positioned elements.

Comment: in play 2.3 SimpleResult renamed as Result...https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2526